# "NotNullConstraintViolationException" Exception although the value shoud not be NULL

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I use the following function to safe the data persistent in the database.

```
public function storeAppendDataDFu1($entity, $pKpPatientid)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    $entity1 = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataAPatient')
        ->find($pKpPatientid);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find DataDFu1 entity.');
    }
    $entity->setFu1AgeRef("5");
    //$pSnnid = $entity->getPSnnid();
    $entity->setFu1KfPatientid($entity1);
    echo $entity->getFu1AgeRef(); 
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    $session->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'Your changes to the DataDFu1 of ID: "'."xyz". '" was saved!'
    );
   // return $entity->getPKpPatientid();
}
```

Everytime when i want safe something, i get this error: NotNullConstraintViolationException

[image: NotNullConstraintViolationException]

I understand, that the FU1_Age_Ref shoud not have the value null, thats the reason why i extended my function with this lines of code:

```
        $entity->setFu1AgeRef("5");
```

but the entity doesn't get this value (what i cant understand) and the exception is still here. So im not shure how i can fix the problem.

The entity defintion:

```
  fu1AgeCalc:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 4
        column: FU1_Age_calc
    fu1AgeRef:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        column: FU1_Age_ref
    fu1DevTest:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 18
        scale: 4
        column: FU1_Dev_test
```

Thanks for your Feedbacks.

Comment: please show your entity definition

Comment: Wow, that insert is **crazy**!  you have to make sure you have the same number of items, of ? and of values.  Then make sure the order is good.  You might be trying to insert a null where it should not, just on the fact that the order is wrong.

Comment: @Nic3500 While the insert may indeed by crazy it is actually generated by doctrine so no real need try and match things up.  This is more a case of someone making a crazy entity and then trying to persist it without understanding how to debug.

Comment: firstone i can't select my datamodel..so i inherted it. I Think the exception comes because the value in the variable Fu1AgeRef would not be changed after the entity->setFu1AgeRef() function..so that the entity with the value NULL in this field will be safed.  but why the vlaue will not be changed.. are the entity which i want safe and the entity which i call the function setFu1AgeRef() not the same..mhm.. jeah sorry but i really dont see the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, at the end it was a misconfiguration in the database. FU1_poorComp was not permitted to be null.